# Name To Decimal To Binary Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary, decimal

I am trying to make a program that asks you about your name, after that it shows the number of every character of your name according to ASCII table. Now I want each number to be converted in to binary and .... I am stuck! :)
Please some help!
Here is my code:

```
using System;


namespace DecimalToBinary
{
   class DecimalToBinary
   {
       static void Main()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Pleasse, enter your name:");
           string name = Console.ReadLine();
           foreach (char ch in name)
           {
            Console.WriteLine("Character {0} is {1} according to ASCII      table.", ch, (int)ch);                
           }
           foreach (char ch in name)
           {
              int decNumber = ch;
              Console.WriteLine(decNumber);                
           }
           Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
           int number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           string binary = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
           Console.WriteLine(binary);             
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly where are you stuck?

Comment: Post your code here rather than expect people to look at it elsewhere; it makes it easier for everyone.

Comment: I want to return to the "Enter a number:" line after i do the binary for the first number so that I can enter each one of the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean convert each of the ASCII values to binary as well as simple integer?

```
foreach (char ch in name)
{
    int decNumber = ch;
    Console.WriteLine(decNumber);                
    for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        var result = Convert.ToString(a, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }             
}
```